# Integral representation of 1/x by f^x

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Looking for integral representation

$$\frac{1}{x} = \int_{a}^{b} (f(z))^x g(z) dz$$

f, g, a, b don't matter.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, $f$ and $g$ are not functions of $x$.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x} = \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-z}\right)^xdz$$ for $x>0$

Comment: $f$ and $g$ completely do not depend on $x$. The integral does, but $f$ and $g$ depend only on the integration variable, which is not $x$.

Comment: $f(z)=1/x$ makes no sense unless $x$ is fixed, which it is not in this context.

Comment: Please show your effort, this site is not here to do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0.$  You may write
$$\frac{1}{x} = \int_{0}^{1} z^x \frac{1}{z} dz.$$